# Need of proof of associative property of symmetric group

Tags: group-theory

I'm a novice in learning group theory.Recently I'm learning about symmetric group.
I understood the closure property,identity property and inverse property of symmetric group but I don't understand the  associative property of symmetric group.Can anyone explain this property in details and with intuition?

Answer (score 7):

If you had learned about the basics of set theory(i.e., sets and functions) before starting group theory, then the associativity of symmetric groups is simply the associativity of composition of maps(functions).

For example see ProofWiki here:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Composition_of_Mappings_is_Associative